# Installing grails on Centos

Tags: grails

When I run `./gradlew libs` when inside the grails directory I get the following error:

```
Could not find property 'org' on root project 'grails-2.1.3'
```

I get the same problem with version 2.2.0, any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You've got a whitespace some where in your path? I've encountered the similar error under Windows.

Comment: Louis: I am also facing the same issue.. have u resolved this.

Comment: Are you sure you need to run `./gradlew libs` for version 2.X?  Latest  [install instructions](http://grails.org/installation) for the master branch shows just `./gradle install`

Comment: Just get the gvm: http://gvmtool.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
rm grandlew libs grandlewlibs
chmod 755 grandlewlibs
./grandlewlibs
```

Does this works?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: With centos i experienced a lot of "could not find/load" issues. for me making sure there aren't whitespaces in the name and giving it permissions worked!